# Cached taxonomy menu block problem?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, routes

I created a taxonomy menu block based on a vocabulary I have. It didn't work how I wanted so I removed it. I have created a view (page) that has the same URL as one of the links in the taxonomy menu block, and that URL displays nothing (which is what happened when it corresponded to a link in the TMB), even though it shouldn't - its preview displays a list of content items. If I modify the view's URL the content displays, if I set it back to what I want it to be it displays nothing.

I've cleared Drupal's cache and even removed the TMB modules, but I still get the same thing.

Am I right to think it's likely to be related to the TMB that I got rid of? And can anyone suggest any steps to getting the content to display on the URL?

Thanks,

Toby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this, I think, but would be interested to hear if there are alternative solutions. I *think* the Taxonomy Menu Block was a red herring - it was just using the URL alias for the associated term references, which exist whether or not a TMB is used. My view had the same URL alias, hence the conflict; setting either alias to something else was all that needed to be done.